# python Regex to find values between 2 strings

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string: `a = '*1357*0123456789012345678901234567890123456789*2468*'`

I want to find a value between `1357` and `2468` which is `0123456789012345678901234567890123456789`.

I want to use regex or easier method to extract the value.

I tried `re.findall(r'1357\.(.*?)2468', a)`, but I don't know where I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of problems here:

1. You're escaping the `.` after `1357`, which means a literal `.`, which isn't what you meant to have
2. You aren't treating the `*` characters (which **do** need to be escaped, of course).

To make a long story short:

```
re.findall(r'1357\*(.*?)\*2468', a)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a slightly more general or flexible method, you can use this:

```
re.findall(r'\*\d+\*(\d+)\*\d+\*',a)
```

Which gives you the same output:

```
['0123456789012345678901234567890123456789']
```

But the advantage is that it gives you the value between any set of numeric values that are surrounded by the `*`. For instance, this would work for your string, but also for the string `a = *0101*0123456789012345678901234567890123456789*0*`, etc...